# Set up a second auto .sccs => .css file in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I've a question about a rails app. I want to make two stylesheets that are automatically compiled from two other ".scss" -files.

Like: 
stylesheet1.scss --> stylesheet1.css 
stylesheet2.scss --> stylesheet2.css

This is what I actually want:

```
_file1.scss, _file2.scss, _file3.scss => mainfile1.scss => application.css
_file4.scss, _file5.scss, _file6.scss => mainfile2.scss => new_application.css
```

The files are located "app/assets/stylesheets/"

Hopefully you guys understand my question :-)

Comment: How can I say to application.css "Compile only these file into you" and the samen for new_application.css

Comment: remove `*= require_tree .` from `application.css` and individually require files like `*= require 'file1'` OR just put all css files to be required in a folder within `app/assets/stylesheets/` and `require_directory` that folder which would load all files inside it.

Comment: `Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( main.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server`

Comment: So I added my comment above but now the app doesnt show up. It loads but doesnt show

Comment: @dkp https://gyazo.com/5ddd3a51d0593a9b5c60e986f3a86ed3
Is this right?

Comment: @LaurentS this would load `preloader.scss` and `dashboard/dashboard.scss` - Is this not working for you ? Add, `*= require_self` as well.

Comment: @dkp it loads but without style
https://gyazo.com/cf94e960332159651dcb24856718e558

Comment: @dkp the bootstrap gem doesnt work, thats why the style isnt working.

Comment: @LaurentS which bootstrap gem are you using ? I would recommend to use: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass     Once you install the gem, create a `main.css` file in your `app/assets/stylesheets` path. Add `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";` to `main.css`. And finally, `*= require 'main'` in your `application.css`

Comment: @dkp Hey I fixed it wit your first comment :-). Can I set a comment to an answer?

Comment: @LaurentS  great!! I have extended the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending comment to an answer.

In order to include few selected stylesheets, you can remove `*= require_tree .` from `application.css` and individually require files like `*= require 'file1'`

**OR**

just put all css/scss files to be required in a folder within `app/assets/stylesheets/` and do `require_directory` that folder which would load all files inside it.